# Prove that $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^+$ $\exists n\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t. $n(n+1) /2 > x ≥ n(n−1)/ 2$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, elementary-set-theory

I think to solve this I should prove
$\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} [n(n−1)/ 2,n(n+1) /2) =[0,\infty)$
Then
$\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} [n(n−1)/ 2,n(n+1) /2) =[0,1)\cup[1,3)\cup[3,6)....... =[0,\infty)$
Is this correct approach?Are there other ways to prove it?If this is correct How should I develop it?
Please, Can anyone offer some assistance?

Comment: This seems perfectly fine to me. Then using your union, for any $x\in \mathbb{R}_+$, there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that the desired inequality holds...